# S3 putObject event - older version received

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am setting up a cloudwatch event to trigger on s3 put object and call a lambda function. I am able to trigger the function successfully and here is the sample code that I am trying to run.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
   console.log("Incoming Event: ", event);
   print("please");
   const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
   const filename = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
   const message = `File is uploaded in - ${bucket} -> ${filename}`;
   console.log(message);
   callback(null, message);
};
```

I am getting an error as the event data does not contain the property "Records". I checked the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) and the event data should contain "Records". The version shown in the documentation is  *"eventVersion":"2.2"*. In the event data I am getting the version as: *eventVersion: '1.07'*

Is there some additional configuration needed to make this work?

Here is what my cloudwatch event looks like:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are not being triggered by an S3 event. How did you set up the event trigger, and what is actually in the event object?

Comment: @jarmod I added a screenshot of my cloudwatch event setup.

Comment: You're seeing a CloudTrail event for the PutObject API call. The format of that event will be different than the equivalent event from S3 (the docs you linked to). If you go to the S3 bucket and apply an event trigger there, it will be in the format you expected.

Comment: @jarmod it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've configured CloudTrail API events. The format of those events is different to the event notifications generated from S3 (the docs you linked to).

If you go to the S3 bucket and apply an event trigger there, it will be in the format you expected. See [Configuring Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html).